# Can I ignore the integration function in the amplitude of a scattering process for the scalar Yukawa theory?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scattering, feynman-diagrams

When calculating the amplitude of a scattering process for the scalar Yukawa theory involving two scalar ($\phi$) and two complex scalar particles ($\varphi$ and $\bar{\varphi}$) I have noticed the integrating function is ignored.  The rules I follow for the mathematical representation of the different type of lines in a diagram are

*Incoming and Outgoing External Lines:*  $$ 1$$

*Propagator (in this case a real scalar):* $$ \int \frac{d^4 k}{(2\pi)^4} \frac{i}{k^2-m^2+i\epsilon}$$

*Vertices:* $$-(ig)$$

In the case of an s-channel diagram I would obtain the amplitude:

$$i\mathcal{M}= (ig)^2\int \frac{d^4 k}{(2\pi)^4} \frac{i}{s-m^2+i\epsilon}$$

**My problem:**

**I have seen in Peskin & Schroeder and in HW solutions that the integral is often ignored whilst all the other elements are kept in the final solution for the amplitude.**

Meaning that the above would have been written as:

$$i\mathcal{M}= (-ig)^2 \frac{i}{s-m^2+i\epsilon}$$

**Why is that so? Can I simply do that, or is there something I am missing?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question is just a metter of the fact that cross section calculations are done in momentum space where the propagator is just given by the expression $$\frac{i}{p^2-m^2+i\epsilon}$$ while the form that you gave, which I think you wrote down wrongly since it's missing the exponential for the Fourier transform and the integration has to be done over the momentum and not the position (for which in fact the expression does not depend on $x$) $$\int\frac{d^4p}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{ie^{-ip(x-y)}}{p^2-m^2+i\epsilon}$$ is the propagator in real space.

Comment: You are right, it does not depend on $x$ but on $k$ in my lecture notes, meaning momentum, so $p$ would be fine too, but I the exponential seems to not be in any of my lecture notes. (The rules I set above were in momentum space)

In the exercise it doesn't specify if they want it in momentum or position space, does that mean I can choose whichever?

Comment: Momentum space is standard for evaluating matrix elements and cross sections. The Feynman rules are way simpler. The absence of the exponential has me worried given that you should be able to go from momentum space to real space, and viceversa, using Fourier transform. That's exactly what you could do to go from your result to the "standard one" if there was an exponential in your propagator.

Comment: So should there be an exponential for the initial (y) and one for the final state (x)? Leading to $e^{x-y}$.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Yes, a complex exponential for which you'll get $$G(x-y) = \int\frac{d^4p}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{ie^{-ip(x-y)}}{p^2-m^2+i\epsilon}$$ where $G(x-y)$ will be the propagator in real space while $$G(p) = \frac{i}{p^2-m^2+i\epsilon}$$ is the propagator in momentum space